# Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, expo, clerk

Today I tried to setup expo (expo router) with clerk and i did not work at all. I always get a `Automatic publicPath is not supported in this browser, js engine: hermes` error, even tough I am just following the tutorial. I tried it a few months ago and it worked perfectly (only difference was I did not use expo router). Has anyone face a similar issue or did I just miss something?

Comment: getting same thing